# Generate Certificate with PKCS#11 in python

Tags: python, openssl, x509certificate, x509, pkcs#11

I write in Python 3, any libraries may be installed.

I have some root certificate and corresponding private key and I want to sign certificate request.

I can do this with pyopenssl easily if root certificate's private key is accessible directly.

However, I have root certificate in HSM and access it by PKCS#11. So I can ask to sign arbitrary data, but cannot read private key. Unfortunately pyopenssl does not support OpenSSL engines, so while native OpenSSL library can use PKCS#11, I cannot access engines from Python. I have found m2crypto library. Author states it supports engines, but I could not find any tutorial or documentation.

I need to somehow sign certificate request. What are my options?

UPDATE:

This
https://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/applied.html#signing-verifying
is not useful, because these functions sign/verify arbitrary data, not certificates, which means I have to format certificate data by myself.

Comment: You are looking for [Python PKCS#11](https://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/applied.html#concepts-in-pkcs-11)

Comment: Already seen this. Library allows import and export of certificate, not signing of certificate request.

Comment: Thereis a chapter [signing-verifying](https://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/applied.html#signing-verifying). [Edit] your Question, why this is not what you want.